# When does Excel use white font on tabs?

Tags: excel, vba, colors, tabs

Excel uses black by default for the Font Color on the tabs. When you change the tab color, the Font Color remains black if the tab color is light, but changes to white when a darker color is chosen.

I would like to mimic this behavior. For which RGB combinations does Excel change to white Font Color?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The possible colors of the tab are `256^3`. Try it out for yourself:

```
Public Sub TestMe()

    Dim cnt As Long

    For cnt = 1 To 256 ^ 3 Step 10
        ActiveSheet.Tab.Color = cnt
    Next cnt

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I have followed the approach suggested by @Vityata. Excel behavior is not straight forward to replicate, but I have found an approximation that serve my purposes:

Considering the color cube as in:
http://matlab.izmiran.ru/help/toolbox/images/colorcube.jpg

Excel *approximately* uses white Font color when

```
R * 20132 + G * 64005 + B * 6630 <= 11675430
```

This will fail in some edge cases (eg: RGB(255,102,3)), but I still hope someone finds this useful. I am leaving the question open in case anyone founds an exact formula.

Thanks for the replies.